Validation of clobber constraints in inline assembly
I maintain C code that has inline assembly used by GCC, Clang and sufficiently compatible compilers¹. Inline assembly statements require constraints to tell the compiler what registers and memory are used as inputs, outputs, and clobbers (i.e. modified without being inputs or outputs).
If we forget to declare a clobber, the code may or may not work depending on exactly how the compiler is compiling and optimizing the C code around it. For example, in a project that I maintain, the code worked perfectly well for years, until one day a new version of Clang made it fail pretty consistently, because a clobber declaration was missing and Clang had started using that register in the enclosing function.
How can we validate that our clobber declarations are correct? Either statically or dynamically. I guess statically is too much to hope, since compilers don't know what's happening in the assembly, and the assembler knows but doesn't keep track, and the ratio of complexity to potential users is high enough to deter people from writing such a tool. But at least I could use a way to instrument assembly statements at runtime, saves registers before, checks their values afterwards, and faults if memory is accessed without the "memory" clobber.
That seems like the sort of thing Valgrind could do with some cooperation from the compiler (to feed it information about the asm blocks), but I haven't found a Valgrind mode or plugin for that.
Contrived example on x86_64:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    (void) argv;
    int x = argc + 10;
    int y;
    asm( /* y = x + 100; clobber dx */
        "movl %1, %%edx\n"
        "addl $100, %%edx\n"
        "movl %%edx, %0\n"
        : "=r" (y)              /* output %0 to y */
        : "r" (x)               /* input %1 from x */
#ifdef CLOBBER
        : "dx", "cc"            /* clobber dx and flags */
#endif
        );
    /* This should print "1 11 111" */
    printf("%d %d %d\n", argc, x, y);
    return 0;
}

Compiling with -DCLOBBER produces correct code that prints 1 11 111. Without the clobber line, on my machine, gcc -O prints 111 11 111 and clang -O prints 1 111 111, because the clobbered register happens to be used for one of the local variables. How can I run some validation tool that complains about the code without the clobber line?
¹  We prefer pure C and if necessary compiler intrinsics where applicable. But there are a few parts of our code base where we need handwritten assembly to reach performance targets or use some features of recent processors. 

Clang's -fasm-blocks support for MSVC-style _asm { mov edx, x add edx, 100 mov y, edx } means it has to be able to parse x86-64 assembly and know which registers are modified by which instruction to generate its own clobber list.  (MSVC-style inline asm can only interact with surrounding code by reading/writing variables in memory, not registers, so it's not efficiently usable for short sequences.)  So if a GNU C extended-asm validator doesn't exist, much of the hard part has already been done if that part of LLVM can be reused.

Instructions with implicit output operands are a problem. But for the rest, I think you could forbid using hardcoded registers via coding convention.

In terms of instrumenting, at least gcc puts #APP and #NO_APP delimiters into the generated assembly. You could write a tool to instrument those by grabbing the constraints from the source based on the line numbers.

Seems like this would be really hard.  What if your template did a push edx / pop edx at the top and bottom?  Is it still necessary to clobber edx?

@DavidWohlferd Is there ever a reason you would want to do that in this use case, vs just accepting that you get a false positive in that case. (Since clobbers have access to all the information and register allocator, so can use far more efficient methods to ensure edx isn't in active use)
